# how to check power button click on BroadcastReceiver class

Tags: android

I want to show spinner only when user click on power button key, here is my code i want when user press powerkeybutton only  spesific broadcast reciver call not any broadcastreciver class

```
public class CloseSystemDialogsIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            ActivityMenu.spinner.performClick();
        }
    }
    // i want to add below this code on my reciver class
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

or if i write this code in my main activity

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        return true;
      }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
```

how do i restrict my code to call only  this
***CloseSystemDialogsIntentReceiver*** broadcast receiver class???

Comment: how do i add specific instruction inside my event key to receieve only CloseSystemDialogsIntentReceiver  reciver my instruction???

Comment: you can set spinner visibilty..invisible.. android:visibility="invisible" ..,and at on click visilble that

Comment: ok how do i shutdown my mobile when button press from application?